# Including scale factor in layoutBounds in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, layout

I'm using JavaFx 8.

From the JavaDoc of `javafx.scene.Node.scaleYProperty()`:

> [...] This scale factor is not included in layoutBounds by default, which makes it ideal for scaling the entire node after all effects and transforms have been taken into account. [...]

How **can** I include the scaling factor in layoutBounds, though?

Some context:
In the following example, when pressing the button I would like the GridPane to react also to the scaling of the HBox whithout having to hardcode the prefHeight of the RowConstraints.

Being able to include the scaling factor into the layoutBounds probably would do the trick, but other solutions are welcome as well.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScalingStandAlone extends Application {

    private VBox vBox = new VBox();
    private GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    private HBox  hBox = new HBox();
    private ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton("Click to scale");
    private Label firstRowLabel = new Label("Some content in text form");
    private Label secondRowLabel = new Label("Some content for scaling");
    private Label thirdRowLabel = new Label("Some moving content");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(vBox, 5.);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(vBox, 5.);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(vBox, 5.);
        root.autosize();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("GridRow Scale Demo");
        stage.setWidth(400);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        root.getChildren().add(vBox);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.getChildren().add(gridPane);
        vBox.getChildren().add(button);
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-spacing: 15;");

        configureGridPane(root);

        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            hBox.setScaleY(button.isSelected() ? 2 : 1);
        });
    }

    private void configureGridPane(Pane root) {
        hBox.getChildren().add(secondRowLabel);

        // Styling //
        firstRowLabel.setStyle("-fx-padding: 5;");
        hBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #800000; -fx-padding: 5;");
        secondRowLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white; -fx-padding: 5;");
        thirdRowLabel.setStyle("-fx-padding: 5;");

        gridPane.add(firstRowLabel, 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(hBox, 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(thirdRowLabel, 0, 2);
        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints());
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().get(0).setPercentWidth(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not at a computer to test this, but try wrapping the `HBox` in a `Group`, (still scaling the `HBox`)

Comment: Wow. this is magic! Thank you, it works like a charm. Can you explain to me why this makes a difference?

Comment: Essentially a `Group`'s layout bounds are the cumulative bounds of its children, after accounting for their transforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadocs for `Group`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Group.html):

> Any transform, effect, or state applied to a Group will be applied to
>   all children of that group. Such transforms and effects will NOT be
>   included in this Group's layout bounds, *however if transforms and
>   effects are set directly on children of this Group, those will be
>   included in this Group's layout bounds*.

(my emphasis added).

Therefore, if you simply wrap your `HBox` in a `Group`, you will achieve the desired effect:

```
    // gridPane.add(hBox, 0, 1);
    gridPane.add(new Group(hBox), 0, 1);
```